# Getting a variable value from a java action listener?

Tags: java, swing, variables, parameter-passing

Sorry for the newbish question, I'm trying to create a GUI for a simple application using JAVA and Swing but I'm stuck trying to get a variable value generated within an action listener from the outside.

```
public geRes() 
{
    setTitle("geRes");
    setBounds(100, 100, 272, 308);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 5, 5));



    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("igen");
    btnNewButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() 
    {

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
        {
              JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
              fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
              fc.showOpenDialog(fc.getParent());
              fc.getName();
        }
    });             
    btnNewButton.setToolTipText("Selec");
    getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);

    JButton btnCivos = new JButton("smbinar");
    btnCivos.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() 
    {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
        {
                File dir = new File(); // I want to use fc.getName() as argument there
```

I'd like to access fc.getName() from the second method, inside a different button. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You souldn't use `MouseListener`, but rather `ActionListener` on  a `JButton`

Comment: why would it be better?

Comment: Because the button can be triggered by other means that just a mouse-click. Depending of the L&F, a button can also sometimes be triggered by pressing `Enter`, or pressing the space-bar if it has the focus. If you set mnemonic, it also works with `ALT+Mnemonic_char` combination.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

make your `JFileChooser` as a global variable so you could call it from the other method.

initialize it outside the method

```
JFileChooser fc;
```

you can place it here:

```
public geRes() 
{
    JFileChooser fc;
    setTitle("geRes");
    ...
```

then when you use the JFileChooser, it will look like this

```
fc = new JFileChooser();
          fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
          ...
```

then, you can call now the JFileChooser from the other method.

```
JButton btnCivos = new JButton("smbinar");
btnCivos.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() 
{
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
    {
       //you can now get the value of fc.getName()
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I tried that but when I attempt to use it I get a null pointer exception at this line File dir = new File(fc.getName());
Also I'm only allowed to define it using final
final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
The rest works, but it doesn't seem to be storing the value from the first method.

Comment: Never mind, this solution works just fine, the problem was that I was using the wrong method as argument, fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath().toString() works instead of fc.getName() since the full path was required. Thanks again!!